# power bi no data view option; need to import first

Tags: import, powerbi, dataview

I have a Problem with Power BI Desktop (September 2019). When I open Power BI everything is fine and I can see all the different views on the left side (report, data and model) but as soon as I want to load data from our server through get data >> Oracle database and choose the database I need, the data view on the left disappears and the option "Enter Data" in the home menu is greyed out and I can't click on it anymore. Since the Query Editor works I always edit the tables there  but when I want to Change something (for example add a column) there is Always the warning : Switch to Import mode and it says that this may cause a huge amount of data being imported. I tried to Import it and it worked but my data changes every day so it's not an option for me because of the data amount. I then thought that there just is no way for me to edit that much but now my colleague said that he has the same database but with his one the data view is not missing and he can edit a lot more.

Now the Question: Has anyone an idea how to solve this because I know that I'm not the only one with that Problem because my colleague said he once had the same Problem but forgot how he solved it.

Thanks

Comment: your oracle data base is cloud or onprem?

Answer (score 0):

There are two (or three if you will) ways to connect Power BI Desktop to your data.

1. Import

   - in this mode, Power BI Desktop downloads the data from the source to the local datamodel. In this mode you have the ability to edit the data as much as you want. You are also able to create new tables to the model with "Enter Data" functionality.
2. Live Connection / Direct Query

   - In this mode, Power BI Desktop creates a live/direct connection to your datasource. You have the ability to use data in realtime (at least very close to it), because  Power BI sends the query directly to datasource. The disadvantage is that you have limited possibilities to edit the data, for example you can't use "Enter data" functionality and the report might be a bit slow to use. If you have a Direct Query -connection to a database, you can use the Advanced Editor to make some adjustments. More info here: Direct query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-use-directquery, Live connection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-ssas-multidimensional, about limitations: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-about)

Actually there's one more, called Composite mode, which includes both of the above (import and direct query). Usually this mode is used to create summarized tables as local datasets and more accurate data as live connection. This makes the model a bit more faster in certain situations.

Based on your question your collegue might have used import-mode or Direct Query mode (import-mode more likely and he refreshes it on daily basis or whenever he is using it). The mode you should use depends on what you want to do with the data and do you want it to be always as up to date as possible.